# When I type, my touchpad becomes unresponsive

Tags: windows-7, drivers, keyboard, synaptics-touchpad

I have a Samsung laptop with Synaptics Touchpad V7.5 running the v16.1.1.0 driver. Whenever I type, my touchpad becomes unresponsive.

Note that I can't find palmsense or an option that allows me to enable my touchpad while typing. Is there a way to fix it or does my computer just not allow it?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? What is your laptop model name/number?

Comment: Win7. Model #: NP350U5C-S01CA

Comment: I've had the same issue on an Asus G75VW I own. The issue seems to be common across laptops with Synaptics Touchpad.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a setting you can apply to prevent accidental pad touches during typing from putting the cursor in the wrong place. I have this on an acer netbook, and I can't remember quite how I set it. I now have a samsung series 3 with the same touchpad, and would like to be able to switch this on and off. I think you just have to keep digging in the help files, troubleshooting, etc both for the specific device and generically in case there's an option within the operating system.

Good luck!

Philip

Answer (score 1):

I am running a Windows 8 Samsung laptop and Synaptics Touchpad 7.5. This worked for me:

Go to `C:\Program files\Synaptics\Syntp`. Scroll down the folder until you find a file called `SynPalmCheck.html`. Delete this file (don't worry it won't hurt your computer). The problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a bit of looking around and giving up, I decided to downgrade my driver to v15.2.20. After the downgrade I managed to turn palmcheck to the minimum. My other driver didn't even have this option from what I saw, so I just downgraded. Now I can move my touchpad while typing. So.. Question answered. Thanks for the help anyways guys. :D

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung laptop  model is NP355V5C-A0EUK. My problem is i cant turn palmcheck off.

- Open the driver for the touch-pad
- You’ll see a list that looks expanded, but really it’s not
- Click or double-click Pointing {--------- this is my problem there is no pointing just finger gestures
- You’ll see Palm Sense right under it
- Highlight Palm Sense then click the cogs on the right-hand side

Comment: I can't tell if this is an answer. Is this your solution to the question or are you having a similar problem as well?

Answer (score -1):

Have the same Samsung Series 3 laptop and I just figured it out:

1. Open the driver for the touch-pad

   You’ll see a list that looks expanded, but really it’s not
2. Click or double-click *Pointing*

   You’ll see *Palm Sense* right under it
3. Highlight *Palm Sense* then click the cogs on the right-hand side
4. Slide the sensitivity to the left (minimum)